# jquery validation plugin with select and checkbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

This is how I use jquery validation plugin wit input text:

```
$('input[id$=txtFirstname]').rules('add', { required: true });
```

and it works, but if want to use it for checkboxes and select it doesn't work...

```
$('input[id$=txtFirstname]').rules('add', { required: true, minlength: 2 });
```

Comment: What selector are you using to access the checkboxes/selects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
<form id='signupForm'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='topic' value='1'>Topic1
    <input type='checkbox' name='topic' value='2'>Topic2
    <input type='checkbox' name='topic' value='3'>Topic3
    </form>

$().ready(function() {
$("#signupForm").validate({
        rules: {
            topic: {
                required: "#newsletter:checked",
                minlength: 2
            },
},
messages: {
            topic: "you must select atleast 2 checkboxes"
}
});
```

Comment: Yes, that works for check boxes,

but doesn't for select:

        $('input[id$=ddlCountries]').rules('add', { required: 'input[id$ = ddlCountries]:selected' });

Comment: For select you could use class='required' ??